# How to convert excel column width to crystal reports width?

Tags: .net, excel, crystal-reports

I have been tasked with porting an existing Excel document to Crystal Reports using .NET, but it must retain the current sizes to the best of my abilities. What I do not know is what the equivalence for the width from excel to crystal reports. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

While perhaps not the most acurate, I started doing my own rough measurements. 19.14 in Excel's units equals roughly 3.64cm, which is 2063.2 twips in Crystal Reports.

Not the best solution, but hopefully this will help others.